# Two conjectures about the prime counting function : $\frac{\pi{(x)}}{\pi{(\pi{(x)}})}<\ln(x)$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $x\geq 100$ then we have as conjecture :

$$\frac{\pi{(x)}}{\pi{(\pi{(x)}})}<\ln(x)$$

I have tested at $x=100$ to $x=5000000000$ without any counter-example.

The first fact :

It seems that the function :

$$f(x)=\frac{\pi{(x)}}{\pi{(\pi{(x)}})}-\ln(x)$$

Can be associated to a  decreasing function $h(x)$ for $x\geq 100$.I have no informations on $h(x)$.

To show it I have tried to use the PNT wich states :

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\pi(x)}{\frac{x}{\ln(x)}}=1$$

But this is an asymptotic information and I don't see any good outcome .

I have also a stronger statement :

Let $x\geq 10^{10}$ then we have :

$$\frac{\pi{(x)}}{\pi{(\pi{(x)}})}<\ln(x)-\ln(\ln(x))-1$$

But I have serious doubt on this second conjecture.

Edit :

Now I have an equality wich is also a conjecture :

Let $x\geq 10^{10}$ then we have :

$$\lfloor\frac{\pi{(x)}}{\pi{(\pi{(x)}})}\rfloor\pm 0.5=\lfloor \ln(x)-\ln(\ln(x))-1\rfloor\pm 0.5$$

Warning with the sign $\pm$ we can have  4 possibilities not simultaneously of course!

Question:

Can you prove or disprove it ? Is it well-know ?

Thanks in advance for your effort !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prove the main inequality, which can be rewritten as $\pi(\pi(x))\ln x > \pi(x)$, we can use [explicit bounds on $\pi(x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities). For example, we know that $\pi(u) > u/\ln u$ when $u\ge17$; therefore when $x\ge59$ (the $17$th prime),
$$
\pi(\pi(x))\ln x > \frac{\pi(x)}{\ln\pi(x)}\ln x > \pi(x).
$$
More precise inequalities ([including these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Non-asymptotic_bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function)) will in principle determine whether the second conjecture is true.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, $\pi(u) > u/\ln u$ holds already for $u \ge 17$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities

Comment: or evalute with the original $$\frac{\frac{x}{\ln x}}{\left (\frac{\frac{x}{\ln x}}{\ln x -\ln {\ln x}}\right )}$$

Comment: First thanks ! A related topic is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension .