# Chebyshev’s theorem and Bertrand's postulate : An exercise .

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers

The title of my question comes from here https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Chebyshev.pdf :

Looks at the reference (link above) we have the following theorem :

### Chebyshev’s theorem :

There exists $a,b>0$ then we have :

$$\frac{ax}{\ln\left(x\right)}\leq \pi(x)\leq \frac{bx}{\ln\left(x\right)},\forall x\geq 2$$

Now the exercise :

---

---

Prove that if $a/b>3/5$ in Chebyshev’s theorem , then $(x, 2x]$ would contain at least one prime
for every $x\ge 32$

---

---

My contribution comes from an earlier question see [Two conjectures about the prime counting function : $\frac{\pi{(x)}}{\pi{(\pi{(x)}})}<\ln(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130364/two-conjectures-about-the-prime-counting-function-frac-pix-pi-pix):

Conjecture :

Let $x$ a positive number sufficiently large then we have :

$$3/5<\frac{\pi{(x)}}{\pi{(\pi{(x)}})\ln(x)}<1\tag{I}$$

Now we have a strong enought information to show the exercise .

Unfortunately I have no idea currently to tackle it .

Update after the comment @Gerry Myerson :

Using the conjecture $I$ for $x$ sufficiently large we have:

$$3/5\pi{(\pi{(x)}})\ln(x)\leq \pi(x)\leq \pi{(\pi{(x)}})\ln(x)$$

On the other hand  :

$$\pi(2x)\geq 3/5\pi{(\pi{(2x)}})\ln(2x),\pi(x)\leq \pi{(\pi{(x)}})\ln(x)$$

So :

$$\pi(2x)-\pi(x)\geq 3/5\pi{(\pi{(2x)}})\ln(2x)-\pi{(\pi{(x)}})\ln(x)$$

Or:

$$\pi(2x)-\pi(x)\geq 3/5\pi{(\pi{(2x)}})\ln(x)-\pi{(\pi{(x)}})\ln(x)$$

Or :

$$\frac{\left(\pi(2x)-\pi(x)\right)}{\ln\left(x\right)}\ge3/5\pi(\pi(2x))-\pi(\pi(x))$$

Or :

$$\pi(2x)-\pi(x)\ge3/5\pi(\pi(2x))-\pi(\pi(x))$$

Repeating the process as :

$$3/5\pi(\pi(2x))-\pi(\pi(x))\ge 9/25\pi(\pi(2\pi(2x)))-\pi(\pi(\pi(x)))$$

And so on...

After that I'm stuck because I don't think we can conclude so easily .

Question :

If my conjecture is true How to solve the exercise ?

Comment: Bound $\pi(x)$ using one bound, and $\pi(2x)$ using the other, and show that the difference is positive for $x\ge32$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the advice I made some progress but I'm still stuck at the end .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

1. $\pi(x)\le{bx\over\log x}$,
2. $\pi(2x)\ge{2ax\over\log(2x)}$, and
3. $a/b>3/5$.

So,
$$
\pi(2x)-\pi(x)\ge{6bx\over5\log(2x)}-{bx\over\log x}=\dotsb={bx\log(x/32)\over5\log x\log(2x)}>0
$$
for $x>32$, where the dots stand for some simple algebraic manipulations invoking basic properties of logarithms.

Comment: Well it's cool but I managed to use $I$ as in my conjecture can you add it or tell me if my progress was not wrong ?

Comment: I don't know, but it seems to me that introducing $\pi(\pi(x))$ just makes unnecessary complications.